# Gradle 4.times. What is $it?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm just newbie in Gradle and while I was reading the Gradle manual I came across the follwoing code example:

```
task count << {
    4.times { print "$it " }
}
```

It prints `1 2 3 4`. Why? What is `$it` and why if we replaced `$it` to "a" we would receive

```
a a a a
```

Moreover

```
task count << {
    print "$it "
    print "$it "
    print "$it "
    print "$it "
}
```

gives the output `task ':count' task ':count' task ':count' task ':count'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I <del>don't even</del> barely know what gradle is, but it seems that `$it` is short for *iterator*.  When you say `4.times (token)`, you're executing `(token)` four times, each time with `$it` bound to the current iteration.

Again, I barely know what Gradle is, but in your second example, `$it` seems to be iterating over the given build tasks.  The current task is `count`, so it prints a string representation of that task.  Without the implicit loop, there isn't a more specific iterator in that lexical scope.

Comment: Hmm... but if I just write print $it 4 times I'll receive `task ':count'task ':count'task ':count'task ':count'`.

Comment: Could you expand that into a full example and edit it in to your original question? My guess is that this is just a generalization of what i've said—iterating over given build tasks

Comment: The variable `it` does not stand for "iterator" it is an implicit variable that Groovy defines when a closure is called with a single argument. You could just as well do `4.times { number -> print "$number" }`. See the [Groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures) for more info on closures.

Comment: @MarkVieira Good to know :) Although, my gut reaction to your example is you're binding `number` to the iterated value.  Your syntax is definitely more unambiguous and so is more correct (imho), but are you also saying that `4.times { print $thing }` would also work, as `$thing` is the only free variable in context?

Comment: No. The code between the braces is a Groovy closure, basically just shorthand for a Java function. That code is being passed an argument. When you define your closure you can define those arguments, just like you would in a regular method declaration (example: `void times(int number)`). The syntax I used above is simply declaring my passed arguments. They can be arbitrarily named. Excluding such syntax the single argument can still be accessed via `it`. I'd suggest anyone working with Gradle to get at least a basic understanding of Groovy since a Gradle build script *is* a Groovy script.

Comment: @MarkVieira Perfect, +1 for the Groovy documentation! :)

Answer (score 3):

From http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#implicit-it

- a closure defines an implicit parameter - 'it'

From http://grails.asia/groovy-times-loop-examples

- 'times' is a method for looping
- You can refer to the variable *it* to know the current index of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The so-called *implicit parameter* `$it` is discussed after the link to Groovy Documentation in the comments above, specifically here: [Implicit parameter](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#implicit-it). It is there for **every** closure, except if there is an explicit empty argument list.

Example with `$it`:

```
def greeting = { "Hello, $it!" }
assert greeting('Patrick') == 'Hello, Patrick!'
```

Example **without** `$it`:

```
def magicNumber = { -> 42 }

// this call will fail because the closure doesn't accept any argument
magicNumber(11)
```

Comment: (Examples are from the link)